# How to write a column header in Excel from an existing file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have this script that scrapes some text and print a list of names in an excel file. I couldn't figure out how to print a column name that doesn't come from scraped text.
The following writes the scraped list correctly:

```
    block = [h5.get_text() for h5 in main_block.find_all('h5', class_='Company_line-title')]
    worksheet.write_column(1,0,block)
    workbook.close()
```

I wanted to add in the first column and row the name "Company". I tried to create a list like:
comp = ['Company']
worksheet.write_column(0,0,comp)

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one cell use write() with cell number and use string variable instead of a list. exm below:

```
worksheet.write('A1', 'Company')  #OR worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Company')
```

or

```
var='Company'
worksheet.write('A1', var)
```

my code:

```
li=['A','B','C']

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Company')  #OR worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Company')  
worksheet.write_column(1,0,li)
```

[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYUzu.png)

Comment: thanks. It worked for a single name. But I use a list like: comp = ['Company', 'Address']

worksheet.write(1,0,comp)
worksheet.write_column(1,0,block)     I get back the error: Unsupported type <class 'list'> in write()

Comment: So you want the name of the first column is 'Company' , the name of second column 'Address' ... Like this right? There is another function write_row(). Try that. I guess worksheet.write_row(0,0,comp) will work